# Out of Memory ao colocar imagem em PictureBox c#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

Estou a tentar abrir uma imagem do tipo JPG, PNG, BMP ou TIFF na `PictureBox`, mas quando tento colocar essa imagem, que foi aberta anteriormente, dá o erro de "Out of memory".
[image: Aqui está um screenshot do erro]

O meu código é para abrir a imagem e colocá-la na PictureBox, mas está sempre a dar esse erro...

A minha questão é se devo usar algum tipo de `Stream` ou se tenho algum erro no código que faz essa exceção aparecer.

O meu código é esse:

```
private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb.Hide();
    wb.Hide();
    OpenFileDialog dialogo = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialogo.Title = "Procurar arquivos no computador";
    dialogo.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";
    dialogo.Filter = "Ficheiros PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf|Ficheiros de Imagem (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif|Todos os arquivos (*.*)|*.*";
    DialogResult resposta = dialogo.ShowDialog();

    if (resposta == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string caminhoCompleto = dialogo.FileName;
        ficheiroaberto = caminhoCompleto;
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ficheiroaberto, FileMode.Open))
        {
            tipo = Path.GetExtension(caminhoCompleto);
            if (tipo == ".pdf")
            {
                upbut.Hide();
                downbut.Hide();
                pb.Hide();
                wb.Show();
                wb.Navigate(ficheiroaberto);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            else if (tipo == ".bmp" || tipo == ".jpg" || tipo == ".png")
            {
                upbut.Hide();
                downbut.Hide();
                wb.Hide();
                pb.Show();
                if(pb.Image != null)
                {
                    pb.Image.Dispose();
                }
                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(ficheiroaberto);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            else if (tipo == ".tif" || tipo == ".tiff")
            {
                upbut.Show();
                upbut.Enabled = false;
                downbut.Show();
                wb.Hide();
                pb.Show();
                if (pb.Image != null)
                {
                    pb.Image.Dispose();
                }
                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(ficheiroaberto);

                SplitTiffFinal(ficheiroaberto);
                filestiff = GetFilesFinal();
                upbut.Show();
                downbut.Show();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Obrigada desde já.

Comment: pb.Image = Image.FromStream(fileStream); deverá resolver o seu problema... segundo a documentação esse erro poderá ser por: The file does not have a valid image format.

-or-

GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Comment: Qual o tamanho da imagem que está a tentar colocar na `PictureBox`?

Comment: @vik podia colocar um exemplo completo como resposta por favor? A imagem é válida e os formatos estão corretos...

Comment: @JoãoMartins O tamanho da imagem pode variar, não é sempre do mesmo tamanho.. Já tentei de 1024 x 768, de 1400 x 934, de 655 x 393, entre outros...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a criar uma instância da `FileStream` e não a chegas a usar.
Ou carregas a imagem através do método `Image.FromStream()` e aí precisas da var *fileStream* que tens no código, ou carregas directamente do ficheiro com o método `Image.FromFile()`

FromStream:

```
using (var dialogo = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dialogo.Title = "Procurar arquivos no computador";
    dialogo.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";
    dialogo.Filter = "Ficheiros PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf|Ficheiros de Imagem (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif|Todos os arquivos (*.*)|*.*";

    if (dialogo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string caminhoCompleto = dialogo.FileName;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(caminhoCompleto, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // ...          

            if (pb.Image != null)
            {
                pb.Image.Dispose();
            }
            pb.Image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);

            // Com o uso de 'using' não precisas de fazer *.Close()
            // fileStream.Close();

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

FromFile:

```
using (var dialogo = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dialogo.Title = "Procurar arquivos no computador";
    dialogo.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";
    dialogo.Filter = "Ficheiros PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf|Ficheiros de Imagem (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif|Todos os arquivos (*.*)|*.*";

    if (dialogo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string caminhoCompleto = dialogo.FileName;

        // ...                          

        if (pb.Image != null)
        {
            pb.Image.Dispose();
        }
        pb.Image = Image.FromFile(caminhoCompleto);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Usando a `Image.FromStream()` resultou na perfeição, muito obrigada.